# How to hide website menu in odoo10?

Tags: web, hide, odoo

My module inherit in odoo -> website module. Here is my code:

```xml
 <record id="make_invisible" model="res.groups">

            <field name="name">Invisible</field>

        </record>
        <record id="menu_shop_sales" model="website.menu"  >
            <field name="name">Shop Sales bolohgui bol </field>
            <field name="url">/shop_sales</field>
            <field name="parent_id" ref="website.main_menu"/>
            <field name="sequence" type="int">21</field>
            <field name="groups">make_invisible</field>
        </record>
```

In my case is:
[image]

if: user = user2 /group is salesman/ hide "**Shop List**" menu

else: user = different user hide in "**Shop Sales bolo...**" menu

Any help to improve this code?

Comment: I'm try:   **<field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>** , but not working in my case. Log is:   WARNING DemoWeb odoo.models: website.menu.write() with unknown fields: users,     Help?

Comment: I dont get your question. Do you want to hide an existing menu?